# What HTTP error code should I use for unauthorised access to a protected image?

Tags: http, error-handling

I am writing a web application that has secure images uploaded by users. These images are only available to the owner when logged in. I am wondering what the best HTTP error code to throw in the case of unauthorised access? Would a 404 not found, or a 403 unauthorised be better?

I am leaning towards the 403, but would it be better to hide the fact that the resource exists to unauthorised users be better?

Comment: 404 if you want to pretend that it doesn't exist, 403 otherwise.

Comment: I decided to go with the 404 as although it is technically incorrect, I don't want users who shouldn't have access to able to even know the file exists. My users shouldn't need direct access to the images anyway as they are used as part of a web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in such case it is up to you, but on your place i would go with 404,
lets "bad guys" think that resource does not exists.

Answer (score 1):

Use 403, otherwise how will the browser know to prompt the user for login?